# Format two decimal places in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to format a number, e.g. `279388242`.

Output: `2,793,882.42`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim myNumber As Int = 279388242

Dim myNumberString As String = (myNumber * .01).ToString("N2") ' 2,793,882.42
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it, but that should get you going.

Comment: hi Tim the result of your code is 279388242.00  my prefered output is 2,793,882.42

Comment: It's there...like I said, not sure it's the 100% proper way to do it, but it's the only way I could get it to work.  It took more than a couple minutes...I think it's past my bedtime :)

Comment: great appreciate your help. sweet dreams :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox(11.0F / 12.0F)
MsgBox(FormatNumber(10000000D, -1, TriState.True, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
MsgBox(FormatCurrency(10000000I, -1, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.True))
```

Comment: Can you explain a little your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myNumber As Integer = 279388242

Dim myResult As String = FormatNumber(myNumber / 100, 2,,, TriState.True)

MsgBox(myResult)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).